# Unmentioned errors in POSIX

Tags: c, posix, language-lawyer

[opendir](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/opendir.html) is pretty much bound to be a memory-allocating function but the [POSIX spec for opendir](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/opendir.html) does not mention `ENOMEM` in the list of possible errors.

What gives would-be-POSIX-compliant implementations the right to set `errno=ENOMEM` in a call `opendir`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [Error Numbers](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_03) in *System Interfaces: General Information*:

> Implementations may support additional errors not included in this list, may generate errors included in this list under circumstances other than those described here, or may contain extensions or limitations that prevent some errors from occurring.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks! Will accept when SO lets me.